# Expanding Nav Forcing Scroll to top on open

Tags: javascript, css

I am pretty new to coding and javascript and I have been trying to create a navigation block that slides in from the left when I click the logo in the top left-hand corner.

I seem to have got the sliding in and out element of the navigation working fine however, if I scroll further down the page and try to open the nav again, the browser window jumps back up to the top of the page rather than staying where it is. Weirdly it doesn't do it when I close the nav, just open it.

This is the script I am using at the top of my HTML to control the nav opening and closing:

```
 <script>
      function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.display = "block";
      }

      function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.display = "none";
      }
    </script>
```

and this is the CSS styling the expanding nav:

```
.expanded-menu {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  animation: animateleft 0.4s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

The animation effect I have on there doesn't seem to be working either. It just jumps out rather than sliding. But I imagine I need to open another question for that.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the associated HTML too.

```html
<div class="expanded-menu" id="expanded-menu">
        <!-- MENU -->
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">
            <img src="images/Backarrow.png">
          </a>
```

and...

```html
<div class="contracted-menu">
        <a href="#" onclick="openNav()">
          <img src="images/nav icons/Cuttsy.png"  class="cuttsy-small" alt="Cuttsy logo">
        </a>
```

Comment: How are you determining whether to call `openNav` or `closeNav`? Can you add the HTML for your logo as well?

Comment: Regarding the animation itself, check out this blog post: https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/. In short, you'll need to animate a different CSS property other than `display` to achieve your desired animation.

Comment: Are you using an anchor tag (`<a>`) for your navigation trigger? For animation effects on transitions, consider another method other than `display`, maybe a combination of `left`/`right`, `opacity` and `transition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to disable the default action, you can use the preventDefault method demonstrated below or using javascript:void(0), like you use in your example.

You just used working link to "#". Normally if used with some existing ID it would scroll to it, but if empty it will just scroll to top.

```js
function foo(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('foo');
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="foo(event)">xxx</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Make sure you are triggering the functions correctly.

For example with a link `a` with the href attribute linking to a javascript function.

```
<a href="javascript:openNav()">Open</a><br>
<a href="javascript:closeNav()">Close</a><br>

<div id="expanded-menu" class="expanded-menu">
  My menu.
</div>
Some Content.
```

See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPQmWE?editors=1111) for a working version.

### Animation

Consider using css3 transitions as a way of displaying animations.

`transition: left 1s;`

Now, transition between `display:none` and `display:block` won't achieve anything, because there are no inbetween states. Instead I would suggest sliding the menu in with the use of the left offset.

You can hide a menu with the width of 200px with a left offset of **-200px**. (Left, top, right, bottom may be negative.) Transitioning the `left` offset to **0px** will look like a transition.

See a working example in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqJvbx?editors=1111).

#### CSS

```
width: 230px;
left: -230px;
transition: left 1s;
```

#### JS

```
function openNav() {
     document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.left = "0px";
}

function closeNav() { 
    document.getElementById("expanded-menu").style.left = "-230px";
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have edited the question and yes, I am linking the to the <a> attribute. Any ideas as to why the browser seems to autoscroll to the top every time to click to open the menu?